# Sci-fi movie where a woman with anemia is immune to iron-absorbing alien goo

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi alien movie, seen on TV sometime between 2005 and 2015.

It was set in a small U.S. town where a blueish alien "goo" begins to absorb iron and steel, flinging it around and melding it into itself.

Anyone who touches the goo instantly dies as the alien goo absorbs the iron from their blood, except for a young woman with anemia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the Syfy channel movie, ***[Iron Golem](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1651894/)*** (2011), also known as *Iron Invader*, also known as *Metal Shifters*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Invader):

> *Iron Invader* (also known as *Iron Golem* and *Metal Shifters*) is a 2011 science fiction television film directed by Paul Ziller. The drama features Kavan Smith and Nicole de Boer. The film premiered on the Syfy channel on February 12, 2011.

From an [IMDB user review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2854490/?ref_=tt_urv):

> The story in the movie is about a bacteria that originates from outer space, crashing down to Earth on a Russian satellite. Two brothers collect the pieces and sell it for scrap metal. However, at the junk yard, the metal becomes animated by the bacteria and adheres itself to a golem that the local junk yard owner is putting together. The bacteria animates the golem and hunts down the towns people in order to extract the metals and minerals from their bloodstreams.

Here's the trailer. You can see the bluish alien bacteria/goo at around the 0:17 mark.

The full film can be viewed on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qILAO-Eb8Yc). There's a scene around the 1:18:49 mark where it's explained that a female character survived a brief physical contact with the alien due to being anaemic.

Comment: Spock can vouch for low iron blood being useful against these sort of menaces.

Comment: Hey, that's it! Thanks for the find